# Extracting function names from a file (with or without regular expressions)

Tags: php, regex, function

How can I extract all function names from a PHP file?

The file has many functions that look more or less like the following. Is a regular expression the best way to do it?

```
public function someFunction(

private function anotherOne(
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could find them with a regular expression:

```
# The Regular Expression for Function Declarations
$functionFinder = '/function[\s\n]+(\S+)[\s\n]*\(/';
# Init an Array to hold the Function Names
$functionArray = array();
# Load the Content of the PHP File
$fileContents = file_get_contents( 'thefilename.php' );

# Apply the Regular Expression to the PHP File Contents
preg_match_all( $functionFinder , $fileContents , $functionArray );

# If we have a Result, Tidy It Up
if( count( $functionArray )>1 ){
  # Grab Element 1, as it has the Matches
  $functionArray = $functionArray[1];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the PHP file is syntactically correct and only contains function only, you can store the result of `get_defined_functions` into an array (anyway, is return an array).

`include_once` the PHP file, compare the latest `get_defined_functions` with the previous array (like `array_diff`). Whichever results returned by `array_diff` are the functions define in the PHP file.

If is an object declaration, the above won't work, although you can make use of function  `get_class_method`, but it is not able to return protected and private methods.

**OR**

```
ob_start();
highlight_string(file_get_contents('class.php'));
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
```

You can have a list of [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) with a style attribute you can filter with.

Comment: Nice solution, with the caveat that by `include` ing or `require` ing the file, you will execute it.

Comment: It's an OOP class so it has functions and properties, not just functions. Will this still work? I also don't understand what the array_diff is for?

Comment: @silow: @ajreal's solution will create an Array of Function Names (before the targetted file is involved), and then another Array afterwards. The `array_diff` function allows you to compare those two Arrays, and see what has been added as a result of the targetted file being involved.

Answer (score 1):

You can write another PHP file to grep for that, or if you have Linux or Mac OS X, you can use something like:

```
grep -P "function\s+\w" myfile.php
```

Answer (score 1):

If your [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) file contains a class which are having methods like above as you mentioned, after including file, you can use `get_class_methods` function of PHP which requires only the classname and it will return the methods of a mentioned class. For more information, see [get_class_methods](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php).

However, if you are sure about classes but don't know the names of it then you can use the first [get_declared_classes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-declared-classes.php) function to get classes, and then you can use the above mentioned function to the methods of those classes.