# preg_split php function in a php file pattern regexp

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching, preg-split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse PHP code to extract function names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8446099/parse-php-code-to-extract-function-names)

I'm working on a script to read my PHP files and get all the functions as a return.

I'm using `preg_split()` to split my file into an array of functions.

I'm having trouble writing the pattern to get all the functions returned (faced issue when the function's name contains the word 'function'. I'm open to any other solutions / advice.

Expected output:

```
array (
  0 => 'function write{$oneparam, $two, $three){return $two}',
  1 => 'function read{$oneparam, $two, $tthree){returne $awesome}',
  2 => 'function edit{$oneparam, $two, $three){return $two},
  3 => 'function delete{$oneparam, $two, $three){return $two}',
  4 => 'function lastfunction{$oneparam, $two, $three){return $two}'
)
```

Comment: Using regexes to parse a programming language is a bad idea.

Comment: You should use `preg_match_all` for that. For more exact results the tokinizer though. Lemme look for duplicates...

Comment: this is just for documentation purposes, I want to document all my functions

Comment: I saw the first one not the second. My bad I'll check it out.

Comment: Instead of using a regex use the [PHP tokenizer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php).

Comment: Mario Your answer was right. It was my mistake. preg_match_all works perfectly. I apologize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this to capture just the names / declarations:

```
#(function\s+\w+\(.*?\)#s
```

Or this to include the body of the function (assuming they're on a single line like in your example):

```
#(function\s+\w+\(.*?\)\s*{.*?})#s
```

[It works for all of your test cases](http://codepad.viper-7.com/h7uVQL), and without any sample input or more details, I can't elaborate further.

Comment: If one wanted to capture the complete function body, the `\{.*?}` part would need a nested capture group; possibly a complete syntax representation (only borderline doable) to understand curly braces in "strings".

Comment: "Or this to include the body of the function (assuming they're on a single line like in your example):" is the expected output

Comment: What if they are not on the same line ? (you know regular php)